# What language for web based application that c# developer can easy learn with ftp and email and is secure?

Tags: programming-languages

For last few months i've learned a lot of C# (for me atleast;).

Recently I've been asked to make an application that:

- Is web based (:()
- A few users have access, and everyone have corresponding settings to their account which I will create
- Have few simple textboxes, checkboxes, upload text file button and send button
- After validation a file will be created and send to a different server (user shouldn't have any idea where) by ftp (user shouldn't see that file)
- Something should monitor an "OK" and "Failed" folder on that server and give feedback to user.
- After all it should send email to me about who did what.
- It should be at least a little secure
- Only around 15 people would have access to it so it can be server-side heavy

I've looked into silverlight, i know it can be done, however it's pretty much dead, I've started making it and I've stumbled upon few problems and I'm a little frustrated by no articles about silverlight past 2011, excluding maybe few about how much silverlight is dead (I'm little exaggerating, but you know what i mean;p).

So my question is - what language would be best, and if possible have easy learning curve for c# developer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you are saying you will need server side scripting so why not stick with c# and asp.net since you already know c#. You could also use visual basic but c# will suffice. Here are some tutorials to get you started.
It will do everything you require.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/
http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Though php is very common and free and has a very big community online which means help is always available when you need it too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with ASP webforms or ASP MVC and have C# for the backend.